# Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window with invalid URL '%3127.0.0.1:3000'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm making a *"open link in new tab"*. I'm using `window.open()` to open new tab.

**my code**:

```
$scope.doOpenLink = ()->
    domain = '127.0.0.1'
    port = '3000'

    window.open("#{domain}:#{port}");
```

but I get this error:

> Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window
>   with invalid URL '%3127.0.0.1:3000'.
>
> ```
> at MyServerScopeController.vm.doOpenLink (base-adb5b1181b.js:4294)
> at fn (eval at compile (angular-29115c1a5c.js:15156), <anonymous>:4:286)
> at callback (angular-29115c1a5c.js:26744)
> at Scope.$eval (angular-29115c1a5c.js:17972)
> at Scope.$apply (angular-29115c1a5c.js:18072)
> at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:1558)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular-29115c1a5c.js:26749)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-888d4551b8.js:4737)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-888d4551b8.js:4549)
> ```

my domain `'127.0.0.1:3000'` rendered as `'%3127.0.0.1:3000'`. any idea on how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of `#{}` in your code? why wouldn;t you just `window.open("http://127.0.0.1:3000")`

Comment: @JaromandaX that is [coffee script string Interpolator](https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/strings/interpolation)

Comment: oh, right, didn't see that the code was coffeescript, thought it was javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with how your string is rendered, if you run the following code in the Chrome browser console, you get the same strange error:

```
window.open('127.0.0.1:3000');
```

The string you're trying to open is not a valid URL, you need to include the protocol:

```
window.open('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
```

The error message is a bit misleading, I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: It seems to be happened after latest update of chrome. open window without protocol works perfect on other browsers.